# Unreachable security context using Feign RequestInterceptor

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

The goal is to attach some data from security context using RequestInterceptor, but the problem, that the calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` always returns null even though it is not null (I am sure 100%).

As I understand that's because the Interceptor is created and is being run in other thread.

How could I solve this problem and get actual data from security context?

My service:

```
@FeignClient(value = "api", configuration = { FeignConfig.class })
public interface DocumentService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     DocumentListOperation list();
 }
```

My FeignConfig class:

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
    return new HeaderInterceptor(userService);
}

public class HeaderInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    private UserService userService;

    public HeaderInterceptor(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

        requestTemplate.header("authentication", a.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, thanks to the article I found [here](https://jfconavarrete.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/make-spring-security-context-available-inside-a-hystrix-command/)

Firstly you need to initiliaze HystrixRequestContext `HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();`.

You have to create your own Context in which you will store information you need to pass to Hystrix child threads.

Here is example:

```
public class UserHystrixRequestContext {

    private static final HystrixRequestVariableDefault<User> userContextVariable = new HystrixRequestVariableDefault<>();

    private UserHystrixRequestContext() {}

    public static HystrixRequestVariableDefault<User> getInstance() {
        return userContextVariable;
    }
}
```

You have to register new concurrency strategy that would wrap Callable interface

```
@Component
public class CustomHystrixConcurrencyStrategy extends HystrixConcurrencyStrategy {

    public CustomHystrixConcurrencyStrategy() {
        HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerConcurrencyStrategy(this);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Callable<T> wrapCallable(Callable<T> callable) {
        return new HystrixContextWrapper<T>(callable);
    }

    public static class HystrixContextWrapper<V> implements Callable<V> {

        private HystrixRequestContext hystrixRequestContext;
        private Callable<V> delegate;

        public HystrixContextWrapper(Callable<V> delegate) {
        this.hystrixRequestContext = HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread();
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public V call() throws Exception {
            HystrixRequestContext existingState = HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread();
            try {
                HystrixRequestContext.setContextOnCurrentThread(this.hystrixRequestContext);
                return this.delegate.call();
            } finally {
                HystrixRequestContext.setContextOnCurrentThread(existingState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So before calling Callable object we set new thread's Context to parent's context.

After that is done you should be able to access your new defined context inside Hystrix child threads

`User = UserHystrixRequestContext.getInstance().get();`

Hope that will help someone.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Really helped me.. I think that you can just use a Servlet Filter - so no need to implement a CustomHystrixConcurrencyStrategy ?